# Why PHP in_array() return false if the value is a variable instead of string?

Tags: php

Does anyone know why the second var_dump() return false?

```
$data   =   'yes';
$data2  =   'no ';
$allowed = array( 'yes', 'no' );

var_dump( in_array( $data, $allowed ) );
var_dump( in_array( $data2, $allowed ) );

var_dump( in_array( 'yes', $allowed ) );
var_dump( in_array( 'no', $allowed ) );
```

Result:

> D:\xampp\htdocs\practice\php\index.php:5:boolean true
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\practice\php\index.php:6:boolean false
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\practice\php\index.php:8:boolean true
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\practice\php\index.php:9:boolean true

Comment: `$data2` has a space at the end of the string. Try `var_dump( in_array( trim($data2), $allowed ) );`

Comment: @creativeartbd because you may probably have space in the `$data2` string `'no '<----`

Comment: OH, I am blind :(

Comment: Try removing the extra space in 'no '

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your $data2 variable there is space **remove** the space

`$data2  =   'no ';`

to

```
$data2  =   'no';
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove Space Behind no in $data2

'no ' to 'no'